# Generic class type doesn't conform to Any

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a problem with storing my generic classes in an array. How should I format the type for my array while keeping the reference to the original type (I know I could do `var myClasses: [Any] = []` but that wouldn't be helpful when retrieving the variable from my array :(

Example is below:

```
import UIKit

protocol Reusable { }

extension UITableViewCell: Reusable { }
extension UICollectionViewCell: Reusable { }

class SomeClass<T> where T: Reusable {
    init() { }
}

var myClasses: [SomeClass<Reusable>] = []

myClasses.append(SomeClass<UITableViewCell>())
myClasses.append(SomeClass<UICollectionViewCell>())
myClasses.append(SomeClass<UITableViewCell>())
myClasses.append(SomeClass<UICollectionViewCell>())
```

***Edit:*** Just to clarify, I have used the collection and table cells as an example, I am not actually planning on storing them together :)

***Edit 2*** `var myClasses: [SomeClass<Reusable>] = []` generates error: `using 'Reusable' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Reusable' is not supported`

***Edit 3*** `var myClasses: [SomeClass<AnyObject>] = []` generates error: `type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'Reusable'`

Comment: did you tried `AnyObject` ? I Think `Any` is for struct only

Comment: corrected question

Comment: @Ondrej, the `SomeClass<UITableViewCell>` can be only one in `myClasses` array or it can be multiple instance of it (basically, of `UITableViewCell`)?

Comment: well, even though I am not sure I fully understand the question, I think I would answer multiple types ... tbh, the same issue is when you not working with array but with a single element variable

Comment: @Ondrej, in this case what's different between two same type in array? i.e. you want to retrieve `SomeClass<UITableViewCell>` and the `myClass` has two of them.

Comment: oh, sorry ... I guess I understand your question now, SomeClass has only one, as implemented in the playground example

Comment: @pacification So in the end I did not understand your question so will get more specific ... in the example I store custom different table view cells which might be of the same type so the current holder won't work ... also, thanks a lot for your help so far, will award a bounty when correct

Comment: @Ondrej, updated my answer again.

Comment: Using `Any` and `AnyObject` is almost always fighting Swift. The answer to all these kinds of problems is generally some form of type-erasue, but it's hard to give a specific answer without knowing how you plan on using `SomeClass` and `myClasses`. Why is `SomeClass` generic rather than just holding a `Reusable`? After pulling things out of `myClasses`, do you need to know the actual type of `T`? (Do you plan to `as?` cast for that? If so, that's usually a mistake.) Are there a limited number of `Reusable` types or is it truly (in you specific app) open-ended?

Comment: (General rule of thumb: if you're mixing classes, protocols, and generics all together, you've often employed too many polymorphic systems and you're going to run into trouble. Try to get rid of any polymorphism you're not actually using in your program.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create some sort of `Holder` class that can accept and retrieve your object:

```
class Holder {

    lazy var classes: [Any] = []

    func get<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> [T]? {
        return classes.filter({ $0 is T }) as? [T]
    }

}
```

And the main part:

```
let holder = Holder()
holder.classes.append(SomeClass<UITableViewCell>())

if let someTableViewCells = holder.get(SomeClass<UITableViewCell>.self)?.first {
    // or filter out again to get specific SomeClass of UITableViewCell
    print(someTableViewCells)
}
```

Or without holder class:

```
var classes: [Any] = []
classes.append(SomeClass<UITableViewCell>())

if let someTableViewCell = classes.filter({ $0 is SomeClass<UITableViewCell> }).first as? SomeClass<UITableViewCell> {
    print(someTableViewCell)
}
```

Comment: But how do I get out a subclass of a cell? I guess that's where the problem lies ...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is adding parent protocol `SomeClass Container` for your SomeClass generic. Then put an array of SomeClass objects inside SomeClass.

```
protocol Reusable { func cakePlease() }

extension UITableViewCell: Reusable {
    func cakePlease() { }
}

extension UICollectionViewCell: Reusable {
    func cakePlease() { }
}

protocol SomeClassContainer { 
    func teaPlease()
    func afternoonPlease()
}

class SomeClass<T: Reusable>: SomeClassContainer {
    var item: T?

    init() { }

    func teaPlease() { }

    func afternoonPlease() {
        teaPlease()
        item?.cakePlease()
    }
}

var myClasses = [SomeClassContainer]()
myClasses.append(SomeClass<UITableViewCell>())
myClasses.append(SomeClass<UICollectionViewCell>())
myClasses.append(SomeClass<UITableViewCell>())
myClasses.append(SomeClass<UICollectionViewCell>())
myClasses[0].teaPlease()

if let item = (myClasses[0] as? SomeClass<UITableViewCell>)?.item {
    item.cakePlease()
}

for myClass in myClasses {
    if let tableCell = (myClass as? SomeClass<UITableViewCell>)?.item {
        tableCell.cakePlease()
    } else if let collectionCell = (myClass as SomeClass<UICollectionViewCell>)?.item {
        collectionCell.cakePlease()
    }
}

myClasses.forEach({ $0.afternoonPlease() })
```

Comment: hi @AleX ... how would you retrieve the items later?

Comment: but here I need to know the type up front ... the problem is that this won't work any custom table view subclass I am afraid ...

Answer (score 1):

You should use array of AnyObject in your case. Because as you know swift is strong typed language and for example

```
 SomeClass<UITableViewCell>
```

and

```
SomeClass<UICollectionViewCell>
```

are different types of objects. As for example Array< Int > and Array< String >, they are both arrays, but still it's a different types of objects. So in this case you'll have to use declaration:

```
var myClasses: [AnyObject] = []
```

and check type of object or typecast them every time you'll need.

```
if (myClasses[0] is SomeClass<UICollectionViewCell>) { do something }
```

or

```
if let cell = myClasses[0] as? SomeClass<UICollectionViewCell> { do something }
```

Comment: but this won't work if I'll have `CustomTableViewCell` .... as the check for UICollectionViewCell would fail right?

Comment: I mean a subclass that is not known in my framework as it has been defined in the app

Comment: @Ondrej Yes, if you'll add element SomeClass<MyCustomCell>(), where MyCustomCell is subclass of UITableViewCell for example, then it will be successfully typecasted only to SomeClass<MyCustomCell>,  if you'll try to typecast it to SomeClass<UITableViewCell> it will fail

Answer (score 0):

Generally the way to type your array would be to go as specific as possible whilst still covering all bases.

What I mean by this for example is storing an array of `UIViewController` objects, even though each will actually be a different type. You wouldn't use `Any` here because you really don't need to be that general.

In your case, why not use `Reusable`? Since all your generic classes conform to it anyway, it is as general as you can go whilst still maintaining convenience.

Comment: It doesn't compile with Reusable either :(